# General approaches to test convergence of $\sum a_n z^{n^p}$ when z is a complex number of unit length 1

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $|z| = 1 $ for some complex $z$,

I know   $\displaystyle \sum z^{n}$ diverges since by summing the geometric sequence, but what can we say about things like:

$\displaystyle \sum z^{n^p}$

and

$\displaystyle \sum z^{n!}$

Are there any theorems I can apply to tackle these kind of questions concerning complex number?

Also, are the sum of the above two things bounded if not convergent?

There are types of series like:

$\displaystyle \sum a_n z^{n}$ where $a_n$ is a sequence tend to zero, by Cauchy convergence property, we know that if z^n is bounded then the series converges.

So I am wondering the convergence of:

$\displaystyle \sum a_n z^{n^p}$

$\displaystyle \sum a_n z^{n!}$

as well

Thanks a lot guys :)

Comment: Nobody? ohhhhhhhhhhh :(

Answer (score 1):

> what can we say about things like:
>   $\displaystyle \sum z^{n^p}$ and $\displaystyle \sum z^{n!}$

They also diverge when $|z|=1$. For a series to converge, it is necessary (though not sufficient) that its terms have limit $0$. It may be called  "Divergence Test" or something like that.

> I am wondering the convergence of: $\displaystyle \sum a_n z^{n^p}$ and $\displaystyle \sum a_n z^{n!}$

When $\sum |a_n|<\infty$, such series converge everywhere on the unit circle. When $a_n\not\to 0$, they diverge everywhere on the unit circle. In between the situation is tricky. For the series $\displaystyle \sum a_n z^{n^p}$ I have nothing else to say. To the other series one can apply a theorem of Zygmund on lacunary series:

- if $\sum |a_n|^2 <\infty$, then $\displaystyle \sum a_n z^{n!}$ converges [almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) on the unit circle.
- if $\sum |a_n|^2 =\infty$, then $\displaystyle \sum a_n z^{n!}$ diverges [almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) on the unit circle.

For more information, look up *lacunary series*.